# Is a ring R a progenerator for the category R-mod?

Tags: category-theory, modules

I have to demonstrate that $R$ viewed as left $R$-module is a progenerator (i.e. a projective and finitely generated generator) of $R$-mod, the category of left $R$-modules.

How can I do this?
I know that a left $R$-module $M$ is a generator of $R$-mod if and only if $M^n$ is the direct sum of $R$ and $R'$ for some integer $n>1$ and some $R$-module $R'$.
Thanks!

Comment: $R^2 \cong R \oplus R?$

Comment: Do you know what "projective" and "generator" means?

Comment: The definition I have found is that a left $R$-module is a generator if it generates every module in $R$-mod and that a $P$ module is projective if, given any epimorphism $p:M \to N$, every morphism $f:P \to N$ can be factorized as $f=pg$ for some $g:P \to M$.

Comment: @Aurel so this is ovious to say that $R$ is a generator

Comment: According to the characterization you gave of a generator in your post, I would say that it is.

Comment: Yes, I agree. And what about being projective?

Comment: I found that every free module is projective.
Moreover $R$ is finitely generated as $R$-module and $R$ is a generator of $R$-mod as @Aurel said. So I'm done, right?

Comment: Yes, $R$ is a free $R$-module, hence projective.